# Problems with top and left option in jQGrid for event viewGridRow, cant parse cursor location

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm having a problem with my jQGrid. I'm trying to make it so that when the viewGridRow event triggers, to set the position of the popup window to the position of the cursor. I have a long list in the grid and defaults put the window at the top of the grid.

atm i have functions that retrieve the cursor position via jQuery:

```
var CursorX;
var CursorY;
$(document).bind('dblclick', function (e) { CursorX = e.pageX; })
$(document).bind('dblclick', function (e) { CursorY = e.pageY; })
```

and the configuration for the viewGridRow is as follows:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('viewGridRow', rowid, {
        top: CursorY,
        left: CursorX,
        modal: true,
        width: 1500,
        caption: "View Item",
        recreateForm: true,
        beforeShowForm: function (form) {
            jQuery("#grid").
            setColProp('last_instruct', { formatter: "unformat" });
        },
    });
},
```

Problem is it doesn't seem to work.

Anyone have an idea what i did wrong?

Comment: I see `var CursorX;` twice. `CursorY` doesn't exist.

Comment: If you set the values of top:, left: manually, do they work to position your grid?

Comment: Plus are you sure your variables are getting set? Is the JQgrid overriding/disabling your event where you set the values of CursorX/Y.

Comment: @Mark when the values are set manually it works, and i checked the values via `alert()` and they turn out fine.

Comment: The values you checked via the alert were inside the `ondblClickRow: function (rowid)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that inside the ondblClickRow event, you display the values of CursorX/Y with your alerts and they are correct?

Comment: @Mark nope, I exchanged this `$(document).bind('dblclick', function (e) { CursorX = e.pageX; })` for this `$(document).bind('dblclick', function (e) { alert(e.pageX); })`. i don't know how to check the values inside tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested on one of my own grids and as wrote the problem is that the jQgrid is processing the ondblClick event before the variables are getting updated.

Do away with your binding of:

```
var CursorX;
var CursorY;
$(document).bind('dblclick', function (e) { CursorX = e.pageX; })
$(document).bind('dblclick', function (e) { CursorY = e.pageY; })
```

and just move to

```
    top: e.pageY,
    left: e.pageX,
```

you will also need to update your ondblClickRow to

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
```

**Edit** (to ensure the jQgrid is recreating a new view/edit, etc window each time.
Ex (Recreate a new edit form each time)

```
    $.extend($.jgrid.edit, { closeAfterEdit: true, recreateForm: true });
```

As a side note, you might want to think about what will happen when a user doubleclicks on an area that produces a form that will be outside the normal viewing area.

Comment: fair enough, but atm is says that e is undefined. I know that I have to define the event somehow but I don't know how. Little more help would be appreciated :)

Comment: see my edit where I define e in the ondblClickRow: function call

Comment: it fixed the problem but only on the firs selection, after that every other item i click the form shows up at the initial spawn point. trying to debug it now, ill post if i fix that. +1 for getting closer to the answer tho :)

Comment: I think you probably need to look at adding in something similar to the following edit above so it recreates the form each time.

Comment: been busy with another task, as soon as i have the chance ill check for a solution and ill post it here.

Comment: the solution worked, i just had a problem with refreshing the coordinates. the funny thing is in the end we wont be using this feature :P. thanks anyway @Mark, you've been a big help :)